# Why does GNOME Shell integration not work on any browsers upon install, 18.04.1 usb multiwriter install

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

Exactly what the question says, when I install Ubuntu 18.04.1 fresh on my Dell Optiplex 9010, I get an error code on every single one of my browsers that native gnome shell host connection (or whatever) is not enabled/supported even though the browser extension is installed. The reason I like GNOME is its extensions, so I backed out of that install, installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04, and upgraded to 18.04.1.... Even so, I feel that this issue warrants a question on this site.

edit: I installed the chrome-gnome-shell package, too. So it can't be that.

Comment: yes, I did. Still didn't work.

Comment: After installing the package, did you login again?

Comment: Yeah I definitely did.

Comment: I really didn't want to reinstall, I don't remember doing it specifically but I'm not dumb, that's the first thing I would have done.

Comment: Also on a fresh install, installing chrome-gnome-shell and then the Gnome Shell Integration extension for their browser works for most people. It will be difficult to track this issue, especially because you reinstalled.